# Error : InvalidOperationException Sequence contains more than one element h

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am king of new at working with asp.net but i am currently in the process of learning, so there is this error that a client got while he was using the web page i will put in the error.
Need to find where and why does this error occur and how do i fix it?

```
Sequence contains more than one element
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains
>   more than one element
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element]
>
> System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source)
>   +5923404
>
> FastMenu.OrdersInfo.rpt_Orders_ItemDataBound(Object sender,
>   DataListItemEventArgs e) +304
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, DataListItemEventArgs e) +0
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.OnItemDataBound(DataListItemEventArgs
>   e) +12178161
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex,
>   ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem) +199
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean
>   useDataSource) +995
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
>   +174
>
> FastMenu.OrdersInfo.dl_Orders_ItemDataBound(Object sender,
>   DataListItemEventArgs e) +1690
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, DataListItemEventArgs e) +0
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.OnItemDataBound(DataListItemEventArgs
>   e) +12178161
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex,
>   ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem) +199
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean
>   useDataSource) +995
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
>   +174
>
> FastMenu.OrdersInfo.dl_AllOrdersData_ItemDataBound(Object sender,
>   DataListItemEventArgs e) +2097
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, DataListItemEventArgs e) +0
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.OnItemDataBound(DataListItemEventArgs
>   e) +12178161
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex,
>   ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem) +199
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean
>   useDataSource) +995
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
>   +174
>
> FastMenu.OrdersInfo.fillOrders() +139
>
> FastMenu.OrdersInfo.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1706
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3178

Comment: Your SingleOrDefault is not working. Possibly duplicates in the list.

Comment: Without any code we cannot help you.

Answer (score 4):

[`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx) throws that exception if the query returns more than one item. That's good because you know that either your query is incorrect or you have inconsistencies in your database (or collection).

So either correct the query so it only returns one item or use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) which does the same but doesn't throw an exception if there are more than one item in the sequence.

Comment: This is not my project and it has been given to me, there are so many SingleOrDefaults in it how can i find which one causes the problem?

Comment: @VladimirLakiBogoevski: look at the exception's stacktrace. `FastMenu.OrdersInfo.rpt_Orders_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e) +304`